# SQLite Database from assets folder is not working in Android Pie i.e API 28

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-9.0-pie

I have added the sqlite file in my assets folder and using the data from the sqlite file in my app. It is working fine upto API 27 i.e Nougat. But the app is crashing for Android Pie i.e API 28. I am using the following methods in my database helper class in the following way. Please help me out.

```
    public Database(Context context, String databaseName) {
             super(context, databaseName, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
             this.context = context;
             String packageName = context.getPackageName();
             DB_PATH = "/data/data/" + context.getPackageName() + "/databases/";
             DB_NAME = databaseName;
             openDataBase();
           }

         public void createDataBase() {
             boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();
             if (!dbExist) {
               this.getReadableDatabase();
               try {
                 copyDataBase();
               } catch (IOException e) {
                 Log.e(this.getClass().toString(), "Copying error");
                 throw new Error("Error copying database!");
               }
             }else{
               SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
               int dbVersion = prefs.getInt(SP_KEY_DB_VER, 1);
               if (DATABASE_VERSION != dbVersion) {
                 File dbFile = context.getDatabasePath(DB_NAME);
                 if (dbFile.delete()) {
                   database.deleteDatabase(new File(DB_PATH + DB_NAME));
                   openDataBase();
                 }
               }
             }
           }

 private boolean checkDataBase() {
     SQLiteDatabase checkDb = null;
     try {
       String path = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
       //checkDb = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(path, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
       checkDb = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(path, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
     } catch (SQLException e) {
       Log.d(TAG, "Error while checking db");
     }
     if (checkDb != null) {
       checkDb.close();
     }
     return checkDb != null;
   }

   private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {
     InputStream externalDbStream = context.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

     String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

     OutputStream localDbStream = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

     byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
     int bytesRead;
     while ((bytesRead = externalDbStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
       localDbStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
     }
     SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
     SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
     editor.putInt(SP_KEY_DB_VER, DATABASE_VERSION);
     editor.commit();
     localDbStream.close();
     externalDbStream.close();
   }


    public SQLiteDatabase openDataBase() throws SQLException {

         String path = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
         if (database == null) {
         createDataBase();
         database = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(path, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
       }
      return database;
     }
```

These are the openDatabase, copyDatabase and create database methods I am using.

This is the crash log -

> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: quran_chapters
>   (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: SELECT  * FROM
>   quran_chapters
>           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native
>   Method)
>           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:903)
>           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:514)
>           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
>           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
>           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
>           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:46)
>           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1408)
>           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1347)

Comment: post your crash log here

Answer (score 2):

If the database doesn't exist, you then use **this.getReadableDatabase();** that will create the database and as you likely have nothing done in the onCreate method the databse is empty.

You then overwrite the disk with the copy however as the database is still open (by `this.getReadableDatabase();`) the empty, tableless database may be fully retained in cache and hence the issue.

The use of a means to open the database when the database doesn't exist appears to be an attempt to get around the issue that the copy fails when it is the first database and at that stage the App's storage does not have a directory named **databases** (opening it creates the directory).

- Note getReadableDatabase will in most instances get a writeable database.

Personally I prefer to, and have not encountered any issues, by :-

1. Never hard coding the database path, rather always using the Context's **getDatabasePath** method. e.g. :-
    `mDBPath = context.getDatabasePath(database).getPath();`
2. Checking if the database file exists to see if the database exists, rather than opening the database to see if it exists. (see example for 3)
3. Checking the parent of the database (i.e. the databases folder) to see if it exists and if not using the File's **mkdirs** method to create the databases directory.  e.g. :-

   `private boolean ifDatabaseExists(String dbpath) {
       File db = new File(dbpath);
       if(db.exists()) return true;
       File dir = new File(db.getParent());
       if (!dir.exists()) {
           dir.mkdirs();
       }
       return false;
   }`
4. Copying the database from the assets to the location specified by the path obtained at 1.

   - As part of 4 I get the asset file, check the first 16 bytes to see if it is a valid SQLiteDatabase (must be "SQLite format 3\u0000").
   - and then proceed to copy the the database from the asset to the database file.

Comment: I have checked the path data/data/my package/databases, the db file exists. The db file also exists in data/user/0/my package/databases. I opened the file using DB Browser, all the data are present in the db file. It works fine upto Android N. It is not working in Android P only.

Comment: my package (with a space) is not a valid package name. Again it is strongly suggested that you get the database as above (or as above except using .getAbsolutepath() instead of .getPath() I've not been able to test on an Android P, but have had feedback that the methodology above does work and has fixed similar issues with Android P).

Comment: I used DB_PATH = context.getDatabasePath(DB_NAME).getAbsolutePath(); But this is not woking as well.

Comment: @AnupamBose You could try using the OpenAssetDB class found at [Android SQLite ErrorCopyingDataBase Error ](stackoverflow.com/questions/53414789/…), this is the the class that the above was extracted from, there is also example usage that show a few uses. It's a bit over the top though but includes pretty comprehensive logging (as well as some other features).

Comment: @AnupamBose Did you got any solution regarding the same? I'm getting the same error and not getting any option.

Comment: @AnupamBose Did you both found any solutions? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: @AnupamBose Did you both found any solutions? I'm having the same issue.